# Python mysql.connector select without locked rows from transactions

Tags: python, mysql, locking

I'm currently working on a Project with MySQL-based Jobworkers. In order for them to fetch a new Job i ran into a problem with row locking:

On Native MySQL (ran 2 terminals and executed following):

```
SELECT id FROM `data` WHERE `status`=0 ORDER BY `created_at` LIMIT 20 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

The Select does not lock the rows what so ever (intended to be this way & what I want)

But running the exact same in Python:

```
import mysql.connector

class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.MySQLConnection(
            host     = "localhost",
            database = "test"
        )

-------------------------

db = DB()
cursor = db.conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM `data` WHERE `status`=0 ORDER BY `created_at` LIMIT 20 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED")
```

Locks all selected Rows even tho no Transaction was ever started for all other Python connections + Native selects in Terminal.

What am I missing here?
Basically all I want is a select to skip locked rows from Python.
Cheers.

Tried enabling autocommit with:

```
db = DB()
db.autocommit = True
```

Also tried:

```
mysql.connector.MySQLConnection
mysql.connector.connect
```

Comment: 1) In innodb everything runs in a transaction. 2) A select query with for update close will lock rows as it is designed to lock rows. So, I really do not understand your question!

Comment: Also bear in mind that sql queries are executed by mysql and not by python! The same query will have exactly the same results no matter what client you executed it from!